# Using TINYGSM Client write function for PubSub's client.publish()

Tags: esp32, gsm, freertos, tcp-ip, mqtt

I have an application of data logger done on ESP32 where a JSON string is published to the MQTT server(QOS 0) using PubSub Library via TINYGSM. I am attaching a sample of the packet sent to the MQTT server.
{"CTRL_ID":"CTID1235","RTU_CH1":55,"PV_POWER_241":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_242":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_243":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_244":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_245":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_246":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_247":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_248":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_249":[50,50,50,50,50],"PV_POWER_250":[50,50,50,50,50]}
which is near about 325 bytes.
50 such packets comprising 325bytes each are sent to the server every 5 minutes. Mutex is taken before publishing the packet and upon publishing it is released. Before publishing GSM network is checked. I noticed that if nothing is sent on mQTT then MQTT disconnect doesn't happen, but when sending data, sometimes it gets disconnected. Note that Sim Card has network connectivity, it's just that MQTT gets disconnected. I am using HiveMQ MQTT Broker. Also sometimes I noticed that after taking mutex the code gets stuck in the client.publish function, due to which mutex is not released. So we have to apply for a restart. Need solution for these 2 issues.[image]